# Hiding #text in a /div wordpress theme homepage

Tags: css, wordpress

We run a site with WordPress and use a template for our design.

On our homepage we have a scroll of our blog posts that includes a title, author/post info, reading time and an "excerpt"?

We're trying to get rid of the "excerpt"

`blog-post-content-list-sider` is the div and the text is just a #text within.

Everything I've looked up is something like `.blog-post-content-list-sider { display: none; }` but that would hide the entire thing not just one aspect of it (if I understand correctly)

This is the code for 1 `blog-post-content-list-sider`

The part that starts with "A Cutting-Edge" is the text that I need removed from each post on our page.

```
<div class="blog-post-content-list-sider">              
<div class="textalignleft subtitle_post_standard">
<a href="https://www.aimblog.io/category/artificial-intelligence/" title="View all posts in Artificial Intelligence">Artificial Intelligence</a>&nbsp;<a href="https://www.aimblog.io/category/emerging-technology/" title="View all posts in Emerging Technology">Emerging Technology</a>&nbsp;<a href="https://www.aimblog.io/category/medicine/" title="View all posts in Medicine">Medicine</a></div>       <h3 class="title_post_standard">            <a href="https://www.aimblog.io/2020/08/30/ai-the-key-to-fertility-treatment/">AI: The Key to Fertility Treatment?</a>      </h3>
<div class="fancy_one ig_meta_post_classic textaligncenter">    
<span><div class="indie_author">By <b> <div class="vcard author">
<a href="https://www.aimblog.io/author/sohail-merchant/" title="Posts by Sohail Merchant" rel="author">Sohail Merchant</a></div> </b> 
</div><div class="indie_on">on </div><div class="updated indie_date">   <b> August 30, 2020</b>     </div>  </span></div>
<span class="rt-reading-time" style="display: block;"><span class="rt-label rt-prefix">Reading Time: </span> <span class="rt-time">4</span> <span class="rt-label rt-postfix">minutes</span></span>
 A Cutting-Edge Discussion about AI’s Eminent Role in Reproduction Intro Artificial intelligence has been widely useful in the diagnosis and treatment of diseases. However, little has been discovered about its capabilities in the realm of fertility treatment. Well, all that is about to change because we will soon experience the first application of AI in […]            
 </div>
```

Comment: Is `#text` a `div` inside `.blog-post-content-list-sider`? (Or you could, you know, share some sample code so we can actually see the thing itself :P)

Comment: Can you please view source of the page and highlight the section with the excerpt?

Comment: @cabrerahector yeah

@ ozgur I had screenshots that I uploaded to imgur but I don't have enough rep to post them

Comment: @ozgur Just updated main post with code. Sorry new to stack

Comment: @Scott did you try my answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

I tested this CSS code and it works. [Codepen link here](https://codepen.io/ozgursar/pen/dyXwbZZ)
Please try

```
.blog-post-content-list-sider{
  visibility:hidden;
}

.blog-post-content-list-sider>*{
  visibility:visible;
}
```

Comment: I put that in function.php of the active theme folder correct?

Comment: I did put it in there and nothing changed. Thank you for the suggestion though. Any thoughts on what I should try next? Maybe Plug ins?

Comment: I suggested a css-only solution. Please try the edited new solution.

Comment: That removed ALL the text IE Title, Author, Clickable Tags etc

We're on the right path though

Comment: Please click the codepen link. It only hides the excerp text

Comment: The thing that trips me up is the section of text I'm trying to remove doesn't have a variable/tag attached to it so I'm confused how to do it. That IS an excerpt right? Officially

Comment: If you add that cas code to your theme’s style.css it should work and hide the text you want to get rid of. Yes, it looks like excerpt

Comment: I've put the code into the custom CSS section and it's removing all of the post info besides the image. Putting into the style.css will result in it playing different?

Comment: Hey man thanks for the solution. It worked perfectly! You're a scholar and a saint